# How To Calculate Age From Birth Of Date and have a validation check for this In Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a column for DOB. However, the age should be over 18 years from today.

How can I have a validation with a custom validation formula where en error should be pop up if the age is below 18 years.

Thanks

Kalyan

Answer (score 1):

In Data > Data validation... please try a Custom formula is of the kind:

```
=DATEDIF(A1,today(),"Y")>17
```